# CSS not applied on HTML content dynamically added in the page using a JS script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In my checkout html page, there's a section dedicated to checked out products:

```html
<div class="col s12 m12 l6">
   <div id="checkout-products-section">
   
   </div>
   <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
</div>
```

In which I'm injecting the content using a js script that builds the content based on the data available in local storage:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    showCheckoutProductsSection();

});


function showCheckoutProductsSection() {

    let checkoutProductsSection = document.getElementById("checkout-products-section");

    let cartProducts = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("cartProducts"));

    cartProducts.forEach(cartProduct => {

        let checkoutProductCard = 
            `
            <div class="card horizontal">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <img class="responsive-img" src="` + cartProduct.image + `"cart></img>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span id="product-title">
                        <img class="responsive-img" src="` + cartProduct.imageTitle + `"></img>
                    </span><br/>
                    <span>Name: </span><span id="product_name" class="product-payment-info">` + cartProduct.name + `</span><br/>
                    <span>Code: </span><span id="product_sku" class="product-payment-info">` + cartProduct.sku + `</span><br/>
                    <span>Subtotal: </span><span id="product_price" class="product-payment-info">` + cartProduct.standardPrice + `</span><span> </span>
                    <span id="product_price_currency" class="product-payment-info">` + cartProduct.currency + `</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            `;
        
        checkoutProductsSection.innerHTML += checkoutProductCard;
    });
```

Everything is working fine EXCEPT for the CSS style that should be applied to the dynamically added content: the styles are PARTIALLY applied.
There's more than one css file: materialize.css and my custom main.css file (containing style defined by my self). The styles defined in materialize.css are working on the dynamically added content (such as 'card horizontal'), but the styles defined in main.css are not working (such as 'product payment info').

Here an example of the class 'product payment info' taken from the main.css file:

```css
.product-payment-info{
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
    color: black
}
```

The file main.css is loaded using a link within the checkout html page (in the head):

```html
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/main.css')}}" />
```

I have another checkout page, for other products, in which I'm not dynamically creating content, and the main.css file is working properly there.

I'm testing with latest version of google chrome.

Comment: That usually means the new elements do not fullfil the requirements of the css. Yet it is difficult to judge without the actual stylesheet. Also, your loop replicates `id`. `id` should be unique in a document.

Comment: may I know which styles are not added? Can you be more specific?

Comment: What you've described, has been a real issue in IE5 and other such old browsers. Like Lain said, check the selectors in CSS match your elements, and fix also the `id` issue.

Comment: People still use IE5?

Comment: I added the missing info, I will also try to univocally define the ids.

Comment: @FSDford: Sadly, I have projects which still have to run on IE6/IE7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the issue: there was a syntax error (a ";" added closing a class after "}") at a certain point of the css file; that issue was the reason why the css classes defined after the syntax error (like the ones that I needed in the checkout page) were not applied in the html page.

Answer (score -1):

This usually happen when you add your style sheet in the  of your html page which will be charged at first
and then Manipulate the DOM to create new Elements dynamically, as a solution you have two options to try :

1 - Add you style sheet inside the  after the script
execution.

2 - Inject the style sheet from your Js script file.